# Calling functions from separate C++ files in main.cpp trouble

Tags: c++, modularity

I have been searching online for solutions to this rather simple problem. My goal is to call a function from a separate .cpp file in my main.cpp file. What I have found thus far has told me to define my function in a separate .cpp file (averageScore.cpp) which looks like:

```
void averageScore()
{
    "Blah, Blah, Blah"
}
```

And then declare the function as a prototype in a header file (Lesson1.h) which looks like:

```
#include "C:/averagescore.cpp"
void averageScore();
```

And finally call the function again in the main.cpp:

```
#include "Lesson1.h"
int main()
{
    averageScore();
    return 0;
}
```

I am currently a CS student and my overall objective with this method of organization and execution is to create a single project for all of the rudimentary programs we must create on a weekly basis instead of creating a new project for every single program. For reference, I am using VScode and have used the following link to help me thus far:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/97779/

My condolences and gratitude are extended to anyone who has taken the time to read through this and help me out!

Comment: Never include cpp files.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the heads up, I just removed the `#include "C:/averagescore.cpp"` from my header file. The only other thing I have in my header file is `void averageScore();` If the function is already defined in the averageScore.cpp, what else should be included in the header file?

Comment: I recommend better describing the problem you have encountered. Removing the `#include "C:/averagescore.cpp"` is recommended because it's a problem, but we can't say for sure that it's the unknown problem you have encountered. A good question will include all relevant code (in [mre] form) any error messages, and if you get as far as running the program, all inputs, expected outputs, and actual outputs.

Comment: Nothing. You should configure your project to compile both cpp files separately and link them together

Comment: The only other thing I would add to the header is an [Include Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to prevent multiple inclusions in a more complicated program. Not an issue here, but a good habit to get into.

Comment: You may also want to invest some time in learning a basic build system like CMake or plain make. It will pay itself back massively later.

Comment: CMake is definitely a good thing to know when using Visual Studio Code. It will help you understand some of the magic  VSC is performing for you in the background. Sometimes the magic goes wrong, and if you know enough for it to not be magic... Life's generally better.

Comment: You should put a header guard at the very top in the `.h` file. `#pragma once` is non-standard, but the easiest way to fix it. Search for `"pragma once"` if it's unfamiliar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you must create a header file, and declare your function there, for example:

**lesson1.h**

```
void averageScore();
```

In a .cpp file, you define that function and include the header you just created:

**lesson1.cpp**

```
#include "lesson1.h"

void averageScore(){
    // Do what you want in this function
}
```

Then you can call that function in your main.cpp by including "lesson1.h":

**main.cpp**

```
#include "lesson1.h"

int main()
{
    averageScore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Marco, thank you very much for your patience and help. The only thing I was doing incorrectly was that I was not including the header file in my lesson1.cpp

Comment: @wisenickel You actually don't _have_ to include the header file - but usually the header file contains more definitions that you need, like `class` definitions etc. In this case, you don't though.